# Defining dynamic pages in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.2

I am creating my first wordpress plugin. In it, the user will have the option to add new cities and view events on those cities.

My client requirement is that the URL must be like this

```
SITE_NAME/cities/NY
```

or

```
SITE_NAME/cities/Califonia
```

What is decided is that i will create a folder cities and If user tries to create a new city i will create a file in that folder with that city, Further more I will add the entry into the database as well.I will insert PHP code into the file as well.

Being new to WP plugins. Is my approach right (for creating files)? Is there any other way?

Comment: Seeing your question, how do you want to deal with wrong entered data like `Califonia` instead of `California` ? And why do you file that as a city?

Comment: im assuming that SITE_NAME/cities/NY gives you an archive like page with all of the cities in NY? and that there would be another page such as SITE_NAME/new-york-city for the single? It would help if we had just a little bit more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maiorano84 wrote a fairly comprehensive guide to setting up the stuff you need, Rather than relying on plugins though, I prefer to show you how to write a plugin to register the custom post type and taxonomy. To that effect, I wrote a little plugin that should do everything you need and it has plenty of comments and links to the docs so that you can understand the *Why* of things.

### Code

#### https://github.com/fyaconiello/WP_Cities_Events

This plugin does several things

1. Creates a custom post type Event
2. Creates a custom taxonomy City
3. Adds custom metaboxes to Event
4. Adds City taxonomy to Event

This plugin does not require any additional plugins to be installed, it is dependency free and only uses WP core.

### URLS

As far as getting the correct **URL Structure**, I would suggest you read this thoroughly: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks.

#### I do not understand the structure you want

```
CITY is a single term w/i the taxonomy *cities*
EVENT is the post single
```

1. `SITE_URL/cities/CITY` would yield a page of all *EVENT* posts in that *CITY*
2. you need a url like: `SITE_URL/cities/CITY/EVENT` to read a specific event in a specific city

### EDIT on how to urls:

In your `Settings -> Permalinks` administration panel select: "Post name" and save.

[image: Screenshot]

Then, go to your Ce `Events -> Cities` admin screen.

[image: screenshot 2]

hover over one of your terms (in my case new york city) and click view.

[image: screenshot 3]

it should open up that term(city)'s list view and the url structure looks like so: http://wp.local/city/new-york-city/

if you need `city` to read `cities`, modify line 102 of the main plugin file i shared with you:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'city'),
```

### EDIT 2

[image: test event is not part of city it is a post categorized by city]

Comment: I dont know whether you understand my question completely,I want URL like this SITE-URL/cities/city_name ,it will show list of eents in that city

Comment: Thank you so much.. I will be glad if you stay there for few more minutes

Comment: I believe that "test event " was the text you wrote in new-york city.. In my case it is not hard coded text,i want to populate it automatically from the events table that have the city attribute as well..

Comment: When try to activate plugin it gave me error--- 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in SITE_URL/plugins/WP_Cities_Events-master/wp_cities_events.php on line 33

Comment: "test event" is not part of city (term content) it is a post categorized by city - See Edit 2 above for a screenshot. I tried several different versions of WP and couldn't duplicate the issue you seem to be having with `unexpected T_PUBLIC`. line 33 of that file is a comment... As a curiosity, what version of PHP and WP are you running?

Comment: I amusing WordPress 3.4.2. What If I want the events to be loaded from DB?

Comment: in my example, they are. what version of php?

Comment: you had hardcoded the event , but what If I want to load stuff from DB?

Comment: that event is not hardcoded. if you look in my screenshot, the sidebar portion "Ce Events" is created by my plugin. Ce Event is a custom post type registered with wordpress. the event "test event" was a post in that custom post type - http://i.stack.imgur.com/9VEwP.png if you look at that screenshot closely, you'll see that the event's data is entered in a standard wordpress editor and saved in the database. the event is categorized by the city taxonomy look in the right hand sidebar of that screenshot.

Comment: I updated the plugin to handle earlier versions of PHP some of the OO stuff I was doing wasnt compatable with earlier versions of 5 and 4, only 5.2.x and up - https://github.com/fyaconiello/WP_Cities_Events Please give it a download and let me know if it activates properly for you. I'm hoping that once you get in it you'll see how it works.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach would work if you WEREN'T using Wordpress, but I would absolutely not advise doing what you're suggesting within the Wordpress Framework.

Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, just about everything you want can be achieved with existing Plugins. I would absolutely suggest taking this route, especially if you don't have much experience with programming Wordpress Plugins.

### Step 1:

#### Install [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/download/)

Self-explanatory. Can't do anything without this.

### Step 2:

#### Install [Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/)

Installing the [Types Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/) will give you a nice interface for registering your own [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and many other features for extending Wordpress' core capabilities.

### Step 3:

#### Register your [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

This is where things start to get complicated. Using Types, Register a Custom Post Type called Event. The reason why you want to have each event as its own Post is because each Event is unique. Cities are meant to encapsulate and define groups of events, which brings us to our next step:

### Step 4:

#### Register your [Custom Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

Think of a Taxonomy as a way to classify things. Wordpress comes with two default Taxonomies: Categories (hierarchical) and Tags (non-hierarchical). In your case, you will want to define for your new Event Post Type a non-hierarchical Taxonomy called "Cities".

### Step 5:

#### Register your [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)

Custom Fields are the easy part. What defines your event? Maybe some fields that define the start and end times of that particular event? A checkbox denoting free refreshments? The sky's the limit. What defining characteristics would all Events have that makes it an Event? Add those in the form of Custom Fields. These will show up on your Event Editor in the form of Meta Boxes. If you don't see the Meta Boxes on the Edit Page for a particular event, be sure to enable it by clicking Screen Options in the upper-right-hand corner of your screen and ticking the checkbox where your fields would be located.

### Step 6:

#### Configure your [Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Much of this can be done either through Types itself (when configuring your Custom Taxonomy), or through .htaccess rewrites, or perhaps even through the Wordpress Permalinks Settings (though, it's fairly limited). My suggestion is to tweak your Custom Taxonomy and Permalink Settings first before messing with .htaccess.

And that's it! Hopefully this should be enough to get you started on everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create City as a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)? You can then define a slug 'cities' and get that result, and also add taxonomies like categories and tags to further aid navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. WordPress gives you a goog API for doing what you want to do: managing pretty URLs (slugs), database operations (you don't need to write/read files for that) and the right code workflow for registering and triggering actions.

So, I think you have to start reading the basics about [WordPress plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) (its philosophy and API) and then just decide if you want to use its custom post types (ready to use) or if you want to create a specific content type.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is fine approach.One more thing that you can do is that instead of adding the code inside the fie..Pick the code from DB.
Make a table in DB,create a column with varchar as datatype and insert the common code in it .

Comment: This is not a good approach for wordpress. While i won't deny that it may work, this should really be managed with custom post types and taxonomies.